# Docker: mounting/sharing a single sock file?

Tags: linux, docker, filesystems, mount

I want to share `php-fpm.sock` between nginx and PHP. The way I've done this right now is like so:

```
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/nginx.docker
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: php_fpm_sock
        target: /mnt/sock
        consistency: delegated
        read_only: true
        volume:
          nocopy: true
    links:
      - php
    php:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: docker/php.docker
      links:
        - mariadb
      env_file: .env
      volumes:
        - type: volume
          source: php_fpm_sock
          target: /mnt/sock
          consistency: delegated
          read_only: false
          volume:
            nocopy: true
volumes:
  php_fpm_sock:
```

i.e. I've moved the sock file from its usual location (`/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`) to `/mnt/sock` because I can't figure out how to mount a single file and I don't want to mount the whole `/var/run` dir.

Secondly, I've configured php-fpm as:

```
[www]
listen = /mnt/sock/php-fpm
;listen.owner = www-data
;listen.group = nginx
; php-fpm runs as `www-data`, nginx runs as `nginx`
listen.mode = 0664
```

i.e., I've given "other" full read privileges because the `nginx` user group doesn't exist in the php-fpm container so I don't know how else I can give permissions to just nginx.

This all feels pretty hacky. So my questions are:

1. How can I share just the sock file between these two containers so that I can move the sock file back to `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`
2. How can I fix the read permissions on this file so that *only* nginx can read it? i.e. how can share linux user accounts across containers?

---

I can also add the `nginx` user into the php-fpm image,

```
RUN useradd -r -s /usr/sbin/nologin -c "Nginx service" -U nginx -u 101
```

And *then* I can set the permissions correctly. The UID must match between both images or it won't work so I've set it explicitly. If `101` had already been used for PHP I think I'd be in trouble again, so I don't love this solution either.

Comment: Using a TCP socket instead of a Unix file socket is more typical Docker practice, and doesn't require any special setup.

Comment: @DavidMaze Perhaps, and that solution does work fine, but I'd still like to know how to do this. I've got some config files with a similar problem; the docker-compose `configs` option is only supported in swarm mode for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kind of have to do it the way you show.  (But mounting the volume over the PHP container's `/var/run` is probably fine.)

You have three big constraints here:

1. Mounts are mounting some external content *into* the container (which can be bidirectionally written to after startup), not publishing content out.
2. Docker mounts the volume into the container *before the main container process starts*, so whatever you're mounting must already exist.
3. The Compose dependency mechanism essentially enforces the order in which containers are *created*, but it won't wait for container processes to actually start.

So by the second constraint, you can't mount the PHP-FPM socket into the PHP container, because it doesn't exist yet when you're running `docker-compose up`.  And by the third constraint, you can't mount the socket into the nginx container either, because it's not guaranteed to exist at the moment the container is created.  ([You can't mount single files out of named volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55548083/10008173) either, but in theory you could work around this by bind-mounting a host directory.)

Since a container only runs a single process, there's probably nothing else in `/var/run` and by its nature it should be okay to hide everything there with an empty volume anyways.  The only thing you might need to manually manage is a pid file.

> How can I fix the read permissions on this file so that only nginx can read it? i.e. how can share linux user accounts across containers?

You need to manually ensure that the `USER` both containers are using have the same numeric user ID.  Note that it's common (if discouraged) to run containers as root which will bypass any controls here anyways.  There's no built-in way to do this.

Comment: There's totally a pid file in there FYI, `/var/run/nginx.pid`. Not that I think php-fpm is going to wreck havoc on that file but it's too bad we can't isolate this better. I've created a group for nginx, php-fpm and for my own user account on the host machine (with matching gid) so we can all have read-write access to the app; this appears to be working well enough.